# bluestack API target is "?" on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bluestacks

i am trying to develop a application that uses Google maps API v2 but since i can't display it on emulator, i tried to use bluestack. it seem to have google play services installed but when i run it, it has an error. i forgot is what error as it is few days ago and did not take down the error. today i wanted to run it again but eclipse did not recognize the bluestack device. usually i make eclipse recognize bluestack is opening bluestack first but it did not work this time.

i believe it is due to this error where the blue stack emulator could not set the target API
[image: emulator target]. the pic is some time ago.

i can run on my real phone where it display the map with no problem but for presentation purposes i would prefer to display it on an emulator if possible. i can also test gps by sending it location.

Comment: Although in `Target` you see a `?` that doesn't mean that you can't install your app on it. I installed my app using Eclipse on BlueStack without any problem. Just ignore `?` and try to select it to install app on it. But make sure that your minSdkVersion is not less than on what bluestack run.

Comment: my min i think is 8, how do i check blue stack min version? i think is that error because in the past my virtual device also faced this before. but when i solve it it seems to work. but i can't do that with bluestack.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `android:targetSdkVersion` on `uses-sdk` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

> *As new versions of Android are released, some style and behaviors may change. To allow your app to take advantage of these changes and ensure that your app fits the style of each user's device, you should set the `targetSdkVersion` value to match the latest Android version available.*

### Example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

For more info, refer **[API Guides - <uses-sdk>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**